# Creating a temporary table and then editing it

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a temp table, append some fields to it and then rename it to original table. I am using the code below but not sure if it is working as intended. Sometimes the result exists and other times it doesn't.

Is there any mistake in the instruction sequence?

```
        Set tbl_copy = db.CreateTableDef("Temp")
        
        db.Execute "SELECT * INTO [" & "Temp" & "] FROM [" & tblName & "]"
        
        db.TableDefs.Delete tblName
        
        Dim field_name As String
        
        With tbl_copy
        
            For col_id = 2 To named_range.Columns.Count
    
                field_name = Format(named_range(1, col_id).Value, "m/d/yyyy")
    
                .Fields.Append .CreateField(field_name, dbdata_type)
    
            Next col_id
          
        End With
      
      
        db.TableDefs.Append tbl_copy
        
        tbl_copy.name = tblName
```

Comment: I'm not strong in the DB commands, so I can't help there, but I'm assuming you have verified each step:
-The source table exists.
-The temp table copy is created as expected.
-The old table is deleted.
-New fields are added properly.

Breakpoints or stepping through the VBA should help answer those. If you can narrow it down to the step that fails, we should be better able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The new table is being created correctly. It shows up in the project. The create table def action doesnt work though , so for the duplicated table no reference is being created so there is no appending happening. I guess a way to answer this might be how can I create a tabledef for an existing table.

Comment: According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createtabledef-method-dao) `CreateTableDef` only applies to MS Access 2013

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the TableDefs object needs to be refreshed if anytime changes are made to underlying database.

```
db.Execute "SELECT * INTO [" & "Temp" & "] FROM [" & tblName & "]"

db.TableDefs.Refresh

Set tbl_copy = tb.TableDefs("Temp")
```

The code snippet above works now and I am able to reference the newly created "Temp" table